# Корректно ли оформлено предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Но только этого недостаточно, необходимо учитывать такие факторы, как качество ведения сделки в целом — а это профессионализм сотрудников — решение вопроса доставки в проблемные регионы, ценовую политику, возможность ведения индивидуальных нестандартных проектов.

Answer (score 1):

"Но только этого недостаточно, необходимо учитывать такие факторы, как качество ведения сделки в целом — а это профессионализм сотрудников, - решение вопроса доставки в проблемные регионы, ценовую политику, возможность ведения индивидуальных нестандартных проектов".

Здесь вставная конструкция, обособленная с помощью тире, относится к первому однородному члену.

Например: Она повесила трубку – аппарат был рядом, – но ещё долго молчала.

Comment: Но это вставное предложение или просто вставная конструкция, не образующая предложения? Потому что у Розенталя в параграфе "Вводные и вставные предложения" ничего не сказано о поглощении тире запятой... http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm

Comment: Да, я исправила ответ. Надо поставить два тире и "перенесенную" запятую. (Тире поглощается при обособлении приложений, а не вставок).

Answer (score 0):

Соглашаясь с Софьей, не могу не обратить внимания на то, что конструкции с союзом "такие, как" требуют не винительного, а именительного падежа. Кроме того, после слов "но только этого недостаточно" лучше поставить двоеточие, ибо дальше разъясняется причина того, почему это недосточно, следовательно: "Но только этого недостаточно: необходимо учитывать такие факторы, как качество ведения сделки в целом — а это профессионализм сотрудников, - решение вопроса доставки в проблемные регионы, ценовая политика, возможность ведения индивидуальных нестандартных проектов".